# Perl Regex: Extract multiline text with oneliner

Tags: regex

I am trying to grab text from a HTML file.
This text spans over multiple lines, thus I am using perl and its regular expressions (instead of grep, awk and sed) to extract this data.
What I need is the text and ID of requirements, that are represented in the source HTML file in the following snippet.

```
<tr>
<td class="mappingtable-content-cell"> ID-3367 </td>
<td class="mappingtable-content-cell"> <span class="no-style-cleanup" style="white-space:nowrap;" title="SW compatible feature mask"><a style="font-size:1em;" target="_top" href="#"><span style="color:#000000;">ID-3367</span></a></span> </td>
<td class="mappingtable-content-cell"> SW compatible feature mask </td>
<td class="mappingtable-content-cell"> The application shall 
provide a bit mask (SW&nbsp;compatible feature mask) with same size 
as&nbsp;parameter ID_HW_FEATURE_MASK where each&nbsp;expected feature 
which should be provided by the&nbsp;HW shall be set to 1.<br>
<br>
<span style="font-style: italic;">Note: The context of each bit is defined by&nbsp;parameter HW_FEATURE_MASK.</span> </td>
</tr>
```

I do this with a bash shell, thus I like to use a perl oneliner.
Also I want all the matched texts to be put into an bash array for later reuse in the bash script.
My oneliner looks like this right now:

```
requirements_ids=($(perl -n0e 'while (m/<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">.*?(ID-[0-9]{2,4}).*?<\/td>.*?<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">(.*?)<\/td>.*?<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">(.*?)<\/td>.*?<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">(.*?)<\/td>/sg) {print "$1\n";}' $polarion_file))
requirements_polarion_reqs=($(perl -n0e 'while (m/<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">.*?(ID-[0-9]{2,4}).*?<\/td>.*?<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">(.*?)<\/td>.*?<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">(.*?)<\/td>.*?<td class="mappingtable-content-cell">(.*?)<\/td>/smg) {print "$4\n";}' $polarion_file))
```

For the IDs this works well, but for the requirements texts I get each word of each match put into a single array cell. How can I have the whole matching text beeing put into a single array cell?

The regex works fine when executing it "in place" on the file, but I actually don't want to change the original file, I just want to grab the texts and use them in bash for rearranging and exporting.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you clarify what exactly you are looking to do? Perhaps it might help to include an example of the expected output.

Comment: what is the expected output of the reqs text that you are talking about.